Support beam replacing an indoor support wall
I would appreciate any help I could get. I am replacing a 10 foot indoor wall, which is a portion of the support beams for the second floor. I am thinking of using two 2 x 12 x 10 boards secured together as the beam. Then resting on supports on each side. How do I know how much weight this will hold? Do you think I need to attach three or four 2 x 12 x 10’s to create this beam?
Thank you for all your help

A picture or a diagram would help.

Most beams will be at least three or four pieces to support a floor.  It seems like it should be an easy job, but you should really get a structural engineer to design it.  Your insurance will require one if changing a house support structure.  Permits also.
